# Проблема с Nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

После добавления в params атрибута

```
images_attributes: [:file]
```

Прикрепляю файл и при создании нового продукта выходит ошибка

```
- Images product must exist
```

В чем может быть загвоздка?

Контроллер:

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.images.build
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.user = current_user

    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product
    else
      render 'new'
    end    
  end

  private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, images_attributes: [:file])
    end
```

new.html.slim

```
= f.fields_for :images do |i|
  = i.file_field :file
```

В модели product `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :all_blank`

В модели image `mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader`

Ассоциации все прописаны. Использую carriewave и Rails 5

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25198

В Rails 5.0 опция `belongs_to_required_my_default` установлена в значение `true` по-умолчанию. Это означает, что ассоциируемый ресурс уже должен быть создан.

Чтобы обойти это ограничение вы можете:

- отключить данную опцию глобально, установив `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default` в `false` или
- установить `optional: true` в методе `belongs_to :product` модели `Image` , в этом случае проверка на существование ассоциируемого ресурса будет пропущена, или
- установить `inverse_of: :product` в методе `has_many :images` модели `Product`, в этом случае ресурс будет автоматически создан.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)